# Should we necessarily express the dimensions of a physical quantity within square brackets?

Tags: soft-question, spacetime-dimensions, notation, conventions

For example, should we write the dimension of mass, e.g. $\mathrm{kg}$  as $[M]$ or is it enough to write it as $M$?

Comment: Is there a reason you ask? If you just write $M$ it looks like an actual mass, whereas the square brackets make it clear to the reader that you mean "dimension of mass".

Comment: The reason is for marks in exam... Will the teachers give marks if we write the dimensions without square brackets ?

Comment: I would use square brackets on an exam. Not just to make things clear to the reader, but to yourself as well. Personally, I switch between $[M]$ and $\mathrm{kg}$ to denote "dimension of mass" in my own notes. In publications you'd probably want to use the first way, but as I said I use the second way as well in personal notes (consistency with the units is needed then!).

Comment: @Vishnu: Try mind-reading your teacher's minds .

Comment: @Dilaton: It is homework actually, since the OP wrote in the comments, "Will the teachers . . . "

Comment: @Dimension10 hm, I only read the question and therefore saw it as more generally asking about the convention of notation for units first ...

Comment: @Qmechanic: If the question arose in the context of whether teachers will "give marks", isn't that homework .

Comment: Hi Vishnu. Welcome to Phys.SE. This particular question (v6) appears to be off-topic/not constructive partly because it is not an actual physics question but rather a notational question of the form "What is the standard notation for this quantity?". Such soft-questions are better asked in our chat room (when you have enough reputation points to enter).

Comment: It is never worthwhile to dispute a question like this with your instructor. For the purposes of the class the correct answer is the one the instructor told you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the best answers to your question is due to the painter René
Magritte :
http://www.wikipaintings.org/en/rene-magritte/the-treachery-of-images-this-is-not-a-pipe-1948
.

[image: http://uploads7.wikipaintings.org/images/rene-magritte/the-treachery-of-images-this-is-not-a-pipe-1948(2).jpg]

It says: "*This is not a pipe.*" There are several ways for interpreting that statement, questionning the language, the image, or the role of representations.

Another answer is given by Juliet: "*What's in a name? that which we call a rose
By any other name would smell as sweet*".
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_rose_by_any_other_name_would_smell_as_sweet

The story does not say whether Juliet actually smoked the pipe.

The point is that notation, as well as language, is a pure matter of
convention for communication with others, as well as with oneself.
Depending on established conventions and cultural commonalities, some
choices may be better than others. It may also depend on the intended
audience willingness to depart from common usage and make some effort
to understand you. Parents will do that with children. Examiner may be
less willing to do it with students who depart from well established
notations or conventions. (What is a "well established notation or convention" ?)

This say, the topic is scientifically very important, as science
requires precision in statement. Not just quantitative precision, but
also precision in concepts. And sciences develops through communication between scientists.

Some of the progress in science is due to improved notation. The use
of a symbol for zero, attributed to Indian mathematicians is the most cited
example. The development of positional numeration, such as the decimal system, depends on it. Other progress is also due to evolution of concepts, of new
views of existing knowledge, rather than new knowledge itself.

But to keep your concepts clear, just watch out what's in the pipe.

Comment: This is probably the best answer that can be given to this question .

Comment: +1 Somebody has read [G.E.D., an eternal golden braid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del,_Escher,_Bach), by Douglas Holstadter.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a matter of notation used to distinguish the variable quantity from it's dimension because the two are different,there is no hard and fast rule to it,you can stick to your convention

Comment: He might stick to *his* notation, but the exam will be graded on the basis of the notation the instructor told him to use... Moreover, there are some fairly common notation conventions out there and the use of square brackets to denote the *kind* of dimension (rather than a particular unit) is quite common to the point that one could be tempted to use the word "standard".

Comment: I am sorry but i answered irrespective of whether there is instructor or not,and if you are forced to use instructors notation why do you want an answer here